# version `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: cardano-db-sync, install

trying to install nix (on a clean fedora 35 server), getting this error, help!

/nix/store/sbbifs2ykc05inws26203h0xwcadnf0l-glibc-2.32-46/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23)

Comment: for me it worked to remove LD_LIBRARY_PATH from env

Answer (score 0):

Try unsetting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like this:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then restart your installation.

If you need more information, please check [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/6665).